# pull from github to digital ocean setup

Tags: git

Hi I have added a virtual host in my apache config files and set up a repo on github. I already have keys because I have other working repos set up.
the vhost is working fine. I know because I used FTP to put an index.html file there on digita ocean. I am able to push my files from local to github. Now I need the last step...to pull files from github up to apache on digital ocean and I cannot remember what to do to set this up

here is the error

fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

Comment: hmm never mind. it wrked with the github url

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell digital ocean server about the github URL, there are several ways to do it:

For a new repo use git clone

```
git clone GITHUB_REPO_URL;
```

For existing repo

```
git remote add origin GITHUB_REPO_URL;
```

Comment: yes this is what I need. to permanently tell git "where" i want to pull from when I am on digital ocean. Right now I have to type everything:          git pull git@github.com:nancymic2/proj3.git but I just want to type "git pull" but am still not sure how to set that. If I add orgin I get this fatal: remote origin already exists.